# How does scanset in "scanf()" works?

Tags: ansi-c

I'm new to C programming and now I'm at the basic input/output topic. I've learned about the various adjustments of the input function "scanf()", and now I'm trying to understand the so-called "scanset". The thing that I can't understand is exactly how it works.

For example the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char str[128];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[A-Z]s", str);

    printf("You entered: %s\n", str);
}

Input sample:
HeLlO

Output:
H
```

As far as I understood, that the scanset is supposed to filter type of characters for the entire string, passing to the string array only the allowed characters. The problem is, as far as I can see - scanset just stops receiving information right after the first unsupported character is met.

For example with the aforementioned input "HeLlO" I expected to form the following input string:

Expected output:
HLO

Do I understood scanset wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understood wrong. From the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> **[**
>
> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a terminating null byte. The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. The string is to be made up of characters in (or not in) a particular set; the set is defined by the characters between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character.

So `%[A-Z]s` matches a sequence of uppercase characters. The sequence must be contiguous, although this is not explicitly stated in the manual. So `scanf` does not discard any intermediate characters that are not in the given set; it simply stops reading when any of those is encountered.